# Determining the slope of the function

Tags: calculus, vectors

Determine the slope of the function $f(x)=-6xe^{-2x}$ at the point with x-coordinate $x=\frac 12$ and what occurs there

What is the equation of the tangent line at the point with $x$-coordinate $x=\frac 12$

Does anyone know the answers for these

Comment: You must use the product rule $(uv)^\prime=u^\prime \cdot v+u\cdot v^\prime$ and the rule $\left(e^u\right)^\prime=u^\prime\cdot e^u$ the find the first derivative then evaluate at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ to find the slope.

Comment: Well, we know the answer. The question is, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales so to find the slope I have to find the derivative of  f(x)=−6xe ^−2x and then plus in 1/2 for x?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. That will give you the slope of the line. Then you find the $y$-coordinate at $1/2$ and use the point-slope equation to find the equation of the tangent line at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Use product rule to  differentiate this 
$$f'(x)=-6e^{-2x} + 12xe^{-2x}$$

To find the equation of tangent follow these steps:

1) Find the first derivative of $f(x)$.

2) Plug $x$ value of the indicated point into $f '(x)$ to find the slope at $x$.

3) Plug $x$ value into $f(x)$ to find the $y$ coordinate of the tangent point.

4) Combine the slope from step $2$ and point from step $3$ using the point-slope formula to get the equation for the tangent line.

Comment: so I differenciate that again?

Comment: No, put $x=\frac{1}{2}$ , you will get slope of tangent